# Mail is not removed from server after setting in MS Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, webmail

I know how to set up the `Leave a copy of messages on the Server` and `Remove from server after x days`.

But, after I configure in the Internet E-mail settings, I found the EmailAccountA's mails still kept in web mail server.

Then, I have configure another email EmailAccountB exactly in same MS Outlook, and that new mail account EmailAccountB is working fine.

Anyone can assist me to re-configure the Internet E-mail Settings in MS Outlook 2010 for EmailAccountA?

Incoming server (POP3) is 110; Outgoing server (SMTP) is 587.

Nothing much configuration in the setting.

Comment: I assume Outlook was open during this time and it is sending/receiving etc

Comment: Are you using this email on multiple clients, and can one client have the check set to always leave the mail on the remote side?

Comment: @DaveRook The Outlook is opening all the time and the process of sending/receiving is taking long duration of time when I check on the Outlook.

Comment: How big is this account? I mean, has it been active for many years and there are thousands of emails? The only time I've experienced similar is 1. Outlook 2013 and IMAP and 2. A spam/junk email used to prevent the emails downloading and therefore, not 'sync'

Comment: @DaveRook, this account active since Jan 2014, it receives many incoming mails and roughly 800 mails a day. I noticed the Send/Receive starts lacking when I backup 3 months mails to another .PST file. And then this account re-downloading the old mails into Outlook, cause it 'hang' over there.

Comment: You have so many emails that it appears as if you are not downloading them all - since the send / receive doesn't finish, I guess it never informs the server to delete the emails... Do you have fast internet connection with enough band width? It is having to download (5 months * 30 days * 800 emails) ~120k emails! It may be that you have to leave Outlook on for a long period of time to get the emails first, then it will be able to start 'house keeping'